# Mirroring censored Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mirror, parking

i wonder if you can help me with a problem a website of mine has been banned in Pakistan and i am trying to mirror it onto another domain that i have. I want to mirror it so that

domain.com/post will also open domain2.com/post

a way i found was to use the mirror domain plugin for wordpress which works perfectly but i end up having duplicate content and as the domain2.com is parked onto domain1.com for the plugin to work i cant set a robot.txt file to stop bots from spidering.

Second option is if i can do the same thing with htaccess anybody have any ideas on how i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the domains to be mirrored, you can redirect from domain1 to domain2 with a 301 redirect and htaccess like you said.

code example from here: http://www.orderofbusiness.net/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It sounds like if you are duplicating content, though, domain2 is doomed to be banned in Pakistan as well.